# ADB returned null value when connect to device over wifi vscode

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, adb, vscode-extensions

I want to connect to the phone via wifi and debug my code. Until a few days ago, it was connected and I was debugging without problems. But recently it encounters the `ADB returned null value` error. The connection steps are as follows using `ADB Interface for VSCode` extension:

1. ctrl + shift + p and select `ADB: Connect to device ip` like below:
   [image: 1]
2. Enable `Wireless debugging` on phone and type given `ip` address and press enter:
   [image: 2]
3. Then type the given `port` and press enter:
   [image: 3]

after few moments, it supposed to show this massage: `Connected to <ip>:<port>`, but it shows this message and does not connect to the phone:

[image: 4]

I also tried another extension called `Android ADB WLAN`, but the result was the same.
what is the problem? how can i solve this?

Comment: What Android version is running on the device? If it has Android 11 and lower have you connected it via USB and enabled adb over IP after the last device reboot?

Comment: @Robert The Android version of my device is 12. I didn't know that after rebooting the device I have to connect again with wire via usb. I tried it and now the problem is solved. thanks!

Comment: But you could also use the new wireless adb mode where you pair the device once and then the connection stays even after a reboot. Just use the `adb pair` command.

Comment: I did it ant it worked. Thanks for your help @Robert